# What is this plumbing fitting?

Tags: plumbing

Today I saw this water hookup in at the site of a farmer's market. What am I looking at? Is this a shutoff? Is it frost-free?

[image]

Comment: looks like a mini hydrant type adaptor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bayonet style sprinkler stand pipe with a pipe nipple, 90 degree fitting and MHT hose adapter.[image: Rainbird coupling key] Lower section similar to this part from Rainbird.

Normal operation is that you lift the cap, push the sprinkler standpipe with attached impact sprinkler in and give it a quarter turn to lock it into the socket. They've adapted the operation to put the water into standard lawn hose in this instance.

Comment: And to the author's question, "yes, it is frostproof, since the actual connection is tucked down below grade"